Where can I find spectra data and light curves of a stereoscopic binary star system?
I am trying to find a suitable source of spectra data and/or a light curve of a binary star (no exact star in particular), with which I would use to find velocity and period, and then find masses etc... This is for a long form assessment, so the point is to use reasonably unprocessed second hand data to demonstrate the physics involved.
I have been looking at the Gaia archive among other things, and I just cant seem to find anything on a star that hasn't already been pre processed into what I am trying to derive, that is, radial velocity and orbital period. I have a feeling that what I am looking for could be found in Gaia's RVS spectrum table tool, but the nomenclature of everything in the documentation is difficult for me to navigate.
Is the Gaia archive the right tool to use for something like this?

No it isn't. The epoch -level Gaia data have not yet been released.

What would be a better option then?
